# Theme Object Empty

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to insert a personalized theme into my component, however when using console.log() in properties in styles I get a return that the object is empty.

**I do not get any kind of error warning, why is this happening?**

[image]

```
// LIBRARY AND MODULES
import React from "react";

// STYLES
import GlobalStyle from "../../styles/global";
import { ContainerPage, FooterContainerPage, FormElement } from "./styles";

// COMPONENTS
import CardRepository from "../../components/stateless/specifics/Cards/Repository/Repository";
import Input from "../../components/stateless/generics/Input/Input";
import Button from "../../components/stateless/generics/Button/Button";

const themes = {
  buttons: {
    searchRepository: {
      bgColor: "#73c894",
      txtColor: "#ffffff",
      hoverBgColor: "#218838"
    }
  }
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    buttonIsDisabled: false
  };

  searchRepository() {
    alert("ae");
  }

  render() {
    const { buttonIsDisabled } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <FooterContainerPage>
          <FormElement>
            <Button
              theme={themes.buttons.searchRepository}
              type="button"
              onClick={this.searchRepository}
              disabled={buttonIsDisabled}
              required={true}
            >
              BUSCAR
            </Button>
          </FormElement>
        </FooterContainerPage>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's `FormElement` doing? Might it be overriding its child's props? From your screenshot it seems that `theme` is `{ type: 'button' }` rather than being undefined.

Comment: The FormElement is just an HTML element (form) that is as container using display: flex etc ...

Comment: It's difficult to guage what the problem might be without knowing the contents of the imported files. Here, I created a demo similar to your case and it seems to be logging `theme` object: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-voice-hx38n

Can you make that demo a bit more accurate to your case in order to reproduce your issue?